# 406 when exception thrown in Spring controller with accept header of text/csv

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a controller with a method that returns text/csv. This works fine for normal success cases, but if an exception is thrown, and I have a header of `Accept: text/csv`, I get a 406 response. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/csv")
public String getCsv() {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

This is in a completely vanilla Spring Boot application (Maven project, importing `spring-boot-starter-web-services`), consisting of nothing but a controller with the above method.

I assume the reason is that the exception is being converted to a JSON error response by the framework. If I remove the `produces` attribute and send `Accept: */*` I get a JSON representation of the exception. Obviously JSON isn't `text/csv`, hence the 406 (not acceptable) response.

Here's an example of a curl request / response showing the problem:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/foo -H 'accept: text/csv'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /foo HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> accept: text/csv
> 
< HTTP/1.1 406 
< X-Application-Context: application
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Sat, 16 Dec 2017 23:04:05 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

However, interestingly, if I look at the `/trace` endpoint in my Spring application, I see something different:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1513465445542,
    "info": {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/foo",
        "headers": {
            "request": {
                "host": "localhost:8080",
                "user-agent": "curl/7.47.0",
                "accept": "text/csv"
            },
            "response": {
                "X-Application-Context": "application",
                "status": "500"
            }
        },
        "timeTaken": "1"
    }
}
```

So, Spring thinks it's returning a 500, but when it gets to curl, it's a 406. I see the exact same thing if I send my requests from PostMan.

I'm not sure what's causing the change from 500 to 406. I assume it's not the client, so my best guess is that Tomcat is doing it. Is there any way to stop that from happening? Or is there some other possibility that I'm missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*==== Original Answer (explaining the expected behavior) ====*

The `Accept` header specifies the format type which client expects the server to respond with. Any variance to this leads to `HTTP 406 - Not Acceptable` error. This error however does not means that the operation failed, however it indicates that the client expectation failed for the specified format.

In your case the `Accept` header carries `text/csv` but server responds with `application/json`, thus the `406` error because there is a clear mismatch.

To correct this behavior there is no change required on server / spring end. Instead the client should start sending `Accept` header which will carry value as `application/json,text/csv`. This will ensure that client expects both formats and supports them in case of valid / error response.

Refer [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/31231) for more details.

**Edit** *22nd Dec, 2017*

The observed behavior is confirmed as a bug by Spring team [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16318). No known workaround available yet.

**Edit** *04th Jan, 2018*

As mentioned in [Spring JIRA comments](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16318?focusedCommentId=156201&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-156201) as a workaround we need to remove the `HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE` request attribute in `@RestControllerAdvice`. The code could look something like below (returns a 500 with some "info" -- a serialized version of the object is also returned).

*Rest controller Advice*

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExampleControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        ErrorResponse response = new ErrorResponse();
        response.setErrorMsg("Server error " + e); // or whatever you want
        response.setErrorCode("ERROR007"); // or whatever you want
        request.removeAttribute(
                  HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE);

        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

*ErrorResponse* object

```
public class ErrorResponse {

    private String errorCode;
    private String errorMsg;

    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public String getErrorMsg() {
        return errorMsg;
    }

    public void setErrorMsg(String errorMsg) {
        this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    }

}
```

**Edit** *27th Jun, 2019*

This is [fixed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/395792b30292bc62a56897a4bdc15ab61c689dc1) now in Spring Framework. The request attribute `HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE` now removed automatically by Spring before handling an exception.

Comment: Ok, so I was able to reproduce the issue. The 500 error you see is because of the `IllegalArgumentException` thrown from controller code. The 406 is because the spring isn't able to locate an appropriate message converter for the error response. I enabled DEBUG logs for spring and got this exception `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation` in the logs (*which is where 406 comes from*). Also I tried configuring additional message converters but no breakthrough yet. Will keep trying though.

Comment: Excellent, yes, that sounds exactly like the vague thoughts floating round my head, but expressed far more concisely, and with actual evidence :) I don't know if message converters are the right solution though, because I think the response should still be application/json, ignoring the Accept header. I think you were right originally that the client should be requesting `text/CSV, application/json`, in order to get a detailed error message, but Spring doesn't seem to respect the fact that the client will accept either type.

Comment: I have created a [bug on spring forum](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16318). Hope to get a response / resolution from there.

Comment: I've tried the workaround, and it works as expected - I simplified it slightly by putting the `@ExceptionHandler` in the controller class as I only need it in a single controller, but the principle is the same. Thank you Mr Bond :)

Comment: I get this problem with springboot 1.5.9.RELEASE *even with an Accept header of */*" weird.

Answer (score 1):

I've also seen this problem when using `spring-hateoas` to return a `VndErrors.VndError` from a global exception handler.

The root cause is that the generated response passes through the `writeWithMessageConverters` method in the `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor` class and the logic in there ends up selecting the *first* content type from the `produces` array and cycles through its message converters looking for something that can convert it to that type.

To make sure we pass that logic, a json content type must be first in that array so that the Jackson HTTP message converter can convert the error:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/foo", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, "text/csv" } )
public ResponseEntity<String> getCsv() {

  if(hasItFailed()) {    
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }

  return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/csv")
            .body("it worked!");
}
```

Now we're left with the problem of legitimate responses - in your case `text/csv`. To make sure those don't end up with a content type of json you have to return a `ResponseEntity` and set the content type header. The logic in Spring's `writeWithMessageConverters` method will look for it and use it.

*NB: this is based on spring boot 2*