# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException for errors with text/plain message response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-web

I have a simple webservice that returns content either as `json` or as `plain text` (depending on the clients' `accept` http header).

Problem: if an error occurs during `text/plain` request, Spring somehow returns a `406 Not Acceptable`. Which is kind of wrong, because spring could as well just write the error out as plain error text, and moreover should absolutely preserve the `400` error status:

```
@RestController
public class TestServlet {
    @PostMapping(value = "/test", produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, "text/csv"})
    public Object post() {
        throw new BadRequestException("bad req");
    }
}

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {
    public BadRequestException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

POST request with `accept=application/json`:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-07-30T14:26:02",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "bad req",
    "path": "/test"
}
```

BUT with `accept=text/csv` (or `text/plain`) shows an empty response with status `406 Not Acceptable`.

I also noticed the `DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult()` is called twice: first with my `BadRequest` exception, 2nd time with `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`. So clearly the rendering of my custom exception fails, but why?

Comment: Look at this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16318 It seams it is a known issue.

Comment: Thanks, probably that's the cause...

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47831530

Comment: This is due to the default exception handling of Spring Boot. Which translates that into JSON and not text. Which is also why you see a double dispatch (first the error and then the error on converting the 400 to a response, resulting in a 406). It probably works if you disable the default exception handling in spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the restrictive Accept header allowing only one content type as response. In case of an error, Spring MVC needs to handle the `BadRequestException` and produce the required content type using a registered `HttpMessageConverter`.

By default Spring Boot has no message converter to produce `text/plain` directly from any object. You may register an `ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter` (as a bean should work for Spring Boot) to allow this and you will get the result of `BadRequestException.toString()` as response body.

I assume a similar problem for `text/csv` but I am not sure how your setup for CSV message conversion looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The condition written in "produces" determines the media type to use for the response to be "text/csv". So For a success scenario it works fine, **

> but when you go for rendering an exception with a JSON body that
>   becomes a problem and gives you a 406 instead.

**

Answer (score 0):

in latest versions of spring framework the problem fixes, but in old versions,as mentioned in [Spring JIRA comments](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16318?focusedCommentId=156201&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-156201) you should remove `HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE` attribute from request
the code might be like this :

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExampleControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        request.removeAttribute(
                  HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE);

        return new ResponseEntity<?>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can handle exception in advice

@ControllerAdvice
class ExceptionHandler{

@ExceptionHandler(value = {HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class})
public ResponseEntity handleMediaTypeException(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException e) {
APIErrorResponse apiErrorResponse = new APIErrorResponse();
apiErrorResponse.setErrorCode("set custom code here");
apiErrorResponse.setErrorMessage("set custom meggage here/ here we can use message from object of exception i.e e.getMessage()");
return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

}